# How to swap a double in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swap

I'm trying to read a double from a file. I need to swap it. `NSSwapLittleDoubleToHost(NSSwappedDouble x)` requires a `NSSwappedDouble`. 
`NSSwapDouble()` requires a `NSSwappedDouble` as well.

`NSSwappedDouble doubleswap = normalDouble;` doesnt work.

How do I convert my double to NSSwappedDouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a double to NSSwappedDouble you can use `NSConvertHostDoubleToSwapped` as per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSConvertHostDoubleToSwapped).

However, if you want to swap a `double` you can call `NSSwapHostDoubleToBig` or `NSSwapHostDoubleToLittle` directly (both a take a `double` parameter).

Answer (score 1):

use `NSConvertHostDoubleToSwapped(double x)`